Не срабатывает хендлер с проверкой на юзера
Я пытался сделать следующим образом:
@bot.message_handler(func=lambda message: message.from_user.username == "айди" and message.content_type == 'voice')

Но бот игнорировал. Однако,если убрать проверку на пользователя, то бот отвечает

Может потому что вы юзернейм сравниваете с айди message.from_user.username == "айди", потому и не срабатывает?
Сделайте message.from_user.id == "айди"
